# New array from array by values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array
    (
        [0] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/outlander.s01e01.avi"
        [1] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/outlander.s01e02.avi"
...
        [15] => link/data_1/d2/Serial/Outlander/Outlander.s01e16.WEBDLRip.Rus.Eng.DV.AlexFilm.mp4"
        [16] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/Outlander.s02e01.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
        [17] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/Outlander.s02e02.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
        ...
        [28] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/Outlander.s02e13.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
        [29] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/S3/Outlander.s03e01.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
        [30] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/S3/Outlander.s03e02.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
    )
```

i'll try create new array by seaseons, my code

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $items) {
    switch (strpos($items, "s0" . $i)) {
        case true: $seasons[$i][] = $items; break;
        case false: $i++; break;
    }
}
```

but it returns

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/outlander.s01e01.avi"
                [1] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/outlander.s01e02.avi"
                [2] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/outlander.s01e03.avi"
                [3] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/outlander.s01e04.avi"
...
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/Outlander.s02e02.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
                [1] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/Outlander.s02e03.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
                [2] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/Outlander.s02e04.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
                [3] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/Outlander.s02e05.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
...
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => link/data_1/Serial/Outlander/S3/Outlander.s03e02.WEBDLRip.NewStudio.TV.avi"
            )

    )
```

From season 2 skips 1 - epizode for each season. How i can fix it? Where's my error? Or how to do this with regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either switching season or adding an episode - that is why you're skipping first episodes.

You should change the switch so that if season is changed, then the first episodes is also added to `$seasons` array.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $items) {
    switch (strpos($items, "s0" . $i)) {
        case false: $i++; // no-break, execute next case;
        case true: $seasons[$i][] = $items; break;
    }
}
```

This code won't work for unordered list of seasons or if one season is missing. This should work better:

```
$seasons = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    // Match '.s[0-9]e[0-9].'
    if (preg_match('/\.s(\d+)e\d+\./', $item, $matches)) {
        $seasonN = $matches[1]; // Season number from preg_match
        $seasons[$seasonN][] = $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
$seasons = [];

foreach($array as $seria)
  if(preg_match('/\.s(\d+)/', $seria, $matches)) {
    $seasons[$matches[1]][] = $season;
  }
```